# How do you assert a function does not revert in Certora?

Tags: formal-verification, certora

In solidity, I have a function:

```js
function do(uint256 a) public view returns(uint256) {
  if (a == 25){
    revert();
  }
  return a;
}
```

In [Certora](https://prover.certora.com/), how do I write a rule/invariant that this function can never revert?

```js
// Rule: do must never revert
 rule doMustNeverRevert(uint128 number) {
    uint256 response = do(number);
    // assert the above line did not revert
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the prover only evaluates non-reverting paths. To tell it to check these paths you can add `@withrevert` after the function name. The `lastReverted` keyword is set to true if the **last** function called reverts, so, in this case, it would be `do`.

In the example, you would write

```
// Rule: do must never revert
 rule doMustNeverRevert(uint128 number) {
    uint256 response = do@withrevert(number);
    assert !lastReverted;
 }
```

Note that checking that functions don't revert this way can be difficult. The prover can find various ways to make a function revert, for example, a non-zero `msg.value` or even by violating some other lower lever checks added by the compiler. It is usually recommended to try to prove that the last revert wasn't for a specific reason (`revert => !condition`) or that the function reverts in a specific case (`condition => revert`).